# how to Stream mic Audio to the same device throw speakers

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, broadcast

I am trying to get audio from the mic and stream it via speakers attached to the aux I used this code and it didn't work in the init of the audio recorder 
but my real question is "is this the right way to do it or there is a better way to do it " and if it is how to fix the problem of init audio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    // the buttons for start and Stop BoadCast
    Button mStartBoadCast;
    Button mStopBoadCast;

    // variables for audio recording
    AudioRecord recorder;
    private int sampleRate = 44100;
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT;
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
    private boolean status = true;

    // audio instance is meant for playing audio input from stream
    private AudioTrack speaker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //init layout views
        initViews();

        // init start boadcast method with the button
        initStartBoadCast();

        // init stop boadcast method with the button
        initStartBoadCast();

    }

    private void initStartBoadCast() {
        mStartBoadCast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startBoadCast();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initStopBoadCast() {
        mStartBoadCast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopBoadCast();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopBoadCast() {
        //todo: add the function to stop boad casr
        status = false;
        recorder.release();
        speaker.release();

    }

    private void startPlayingAudio(byte[] buffer, int minBufSize) {

        status = true;


        speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        speaker.play();

        while (status) {

            speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
            Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");


        }


    }

    private void startBoadCast() {


        status = true;


        Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];


        recorder = findAudioRecord();
        Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");


        recorder.startRecording();


        while (status) {


            //reading data from MIC into buffer
            minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            /**
             * here we finished recording then we will start to play the recorded audio
             */
            startPlayingAudio(buffer, minBufSize);

            System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " + minBufSize);
        }


    }

    private void initViews() {
        mStartBoadCast = findViewById(R.id.start_boadcast);
        mStopBoadCast = findViewById(R.id.stop_boadcast);
    }


    private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[]{8000, 11025, 22050, 44100};

    public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
        for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
            for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
                for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                                + channelConfig);
                        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                        if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                            if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                                return recorder;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal is in the detail, You didn't tell us how this does not work or what kind of error it gives. I had to do a similar program and this is how i did it.

The Audio Class first:

```
class audio {

AudioRecord arec;
AudioTrack atrack;
private volatile boolean isRecording= false;

private static int buffer_size;
//final short[] buffer = new short[buffersize];
//short[] readbuffer = new short[buffersize];


private int sample_rate;//the rate of recording used to initialise AudioRecord
private int[] msample_rates = new int[]{44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};

private short audio_format;
private short[] audio_formats = new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT};

private short channel_config;
private short[] channel_configs = new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO};
private short channelOutConfig;

public AudioRecord findAudioRecord(){
    for (int rate_f : msample_rates){
        for (short audioformat_f : audio_formats){
            for (short channelconfig_f : channel_configs){

                try {
                    Log.i("AudioC", "Attempting rate : "+ rate_f + "Hz, bits: " + audioformat_f + ", Channel: " + channelconfig_f);
                    int buffersize_f = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate_f, channelconfig_f, audioformat_f);

                    Log.i("AudioC", "Buffersize: " + buffersize_f);
                    if (buffersize_f != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE){
                        //Check of we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, rate_f, channelconfig_f, audioformat_f, buffersize_f);

                        Log.i("AudioC", "Recorder State Value: " + recorder.getState());
                        if(recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){
                            Log.i("Audio", "Success");
                            //global values
                            buffer_size = buffersize_f;
                            sample_rate = rate_f;
                            audio_format = audioformat_f;
                            channel_config = channelconfig_f;

                            if (channelconfig_f == AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO) channelOutConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
                            else channelOutConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
                            return recorder;
                        }

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("AudioC", rate_f + " Exception, keep trying." + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i("AudioC", "Failed to initialise the audio record state");
    return null;

}

public void run(){

    isRecording = true;
    //initialization
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

    //getValidSampleRates();
   // int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sample_rate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
   // arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sample_rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
    //The above lines were replaced by a looping function in order to test every occurrence of rate,audioformat and channelconfig which is usually different for different adroid devices
    arec = findAudioRecord();//Still failed to initialize the Audio Recorder


    atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
            sample_rate,
            channelOutConfig,
            audio_format,
            buffer_size,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    atrack.setPlaybackRate(sample_rate);
    //run
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
    arec.startRecording();
    atrack.play();

            while (isRecording){
                arec.read(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
                atrack.write(buffer, 0,buffer.length);
            }
            arec.release();
            atrack.release();
}


public void stop(){
    isRecording= false;
    arec.stop();
    atrack.stop();
    arec.release();
    atrack.release();
}
```

}

And then call it from a thread or an intent service from the activity(Main Activity) to avoid the app from freezing.
Example from thread:

```
class playerTask implements Runnable{

public audio mic_player = new audio(); //The audio class we declared above
private Thread t;

public playerTask(){

}
public void execTask(){

    t = new Thread(this,"playing_Thread");
    t.start();

}
public void abortTask(){

    mic_player.stop();
}

public void run(){
    mic_player.run();

}
```

}

And then from your activity,

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ToggleButton onOff;
    boolean playing = false;


    // Once the app start recording, the recording thread freezes the screen because of the while loop, the it works
    //directly with the main thread hence doesnt release the hand until forced to stop
    //For that we need to create it's own thread hence being able to play sound without freezing the remaining of the app
    //private Handler myHandler


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);

        //Handler

        //Route the sound to the AUX only and always
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
        audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);

        final playerTask pl_task = new playerTask();
      /////Use a toggle button to start or stop the recording///You could use anything
        onOff = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.OnOff);
        onOff.setTextOff("PLAY");
        onOff.setTextOn("STOP");
        onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonview, boolean isCheked){
                //Running thread

                if (isCheked){
                    messagefield.setText("Playing");
                    pl_task.execTask();  ///Start streaming

                }
                else{
                    messagefield.setText("Not Playing");
                    pl_task.abortTask();  ///Stop streaming

                }
            }
        });
```

}

These are the permissions you need to request:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: I didn't know the right way to do it so this is why I just put the code  i used your solution but it gived me this error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid zero channel mask
at the line   
     atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, sample_rate, channel_config, audio_format, buffer_size, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

Comment: Yeah i have edited the answer and tested it, you're right about the IllegalArgumentException. It was caused by invalid channels, you need to request  those permissions to be allowed to use AudioRecord and AudioTrack

Comment: Can you please help me @RachidRajjys transferring one mobile audio to another working fine with this code val audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
                        .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                        .setSampleRate(buffer.sampleRate)
                        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                        .build()
but when i try transfer audio from android tv box its not working.. i think its something with setChannelMask code i dont what to set for tv i try channel out there but its crashing